# geometry circle proof

Tags: geometry

Use a common notion to prove the following result: If $P$ and $Q$ are any points on a circle with center $O$ and radius $OA$ then $OP$ is congruent to $OQ$.

Since $O$ is the center and $P$ & $Q$ are any where on the circle it would be the same distance since a circle is equidistant all around? I'm not sure how you formally prove this.

Help please?

Comment: Can you include a description of the relevant axioms/definitions that you are working with? It is hard for other users to help you formally prove something without knowing these things.

Comment: If anybody asks you why they are equal, just quote "radii of the same circle".

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy yourself using Euclud's axioms then a circle is defined this way:

> A circle is a plane figure contained by one curve (called the circumference) with a given point lying within the figure such that all the straight lines joining the given point to the circumference **are equal to one another**. ([Source](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dwh/books/eg00/append-A.html))

If you are using instead geometry defined with a distance function, then the circle of radius $r$ and center $c$ is *defined* to be the set of points at distance $r$ from $c$.

Either way, it seems to me that any two radii are congruent (equal/same length) *by definition*, and there is nothing to prove.

It could be you are using some definition I'm not familiar with. Let me know if that's the case.